# How do you Apply H.264 Compression to a CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video-toolbox

I have been trying to apply H.264 encoding to a `CMSampleBuffer` using `VideoToolBox` in Swift, I am very new to Swift and do not know how to do this if the compression turns the `CMSampleBuffer` into a `CVPixelBuffer` that is fine too as I need to turn it into `NSData` in the end. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Z3RO, 
Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did but it was in a private repo I do not have access to anymore, I am very sorry.